# Simultaneous gesture interferes with Stepper

Tags: swiftui

I have implemented a gesture listener on my view to listen for when a user taps on the screen. However, I've found that it interferes with the `Stepper` elements on my page. I can't tap the + or - buttons on the stepper. Is there a way to fix this, or are there any workarounds to get the gesture listener working with the stepper at the same time?

```
VStack {
   Stepper(...)
}
.simultaneousGesture(
    TapGesture()
        .onEnded {
            resetTimer()
        }
)
```