# SwiftUI - Search bar doesn't work when drag gesture is added

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a tab view at the bottom of main view. Tapping on the tab opens another view which would be a custom modal behind the tab view (in this sample code it's showing up as main view). Anyways, main issue is that this view has a search bar and whenever drag gesture is added to this view, then search bar doesn't work i.e. tapping on the search bar doesn't bring up the keyboard.

How do I make search bar work when drag gesture is present?

I have too much code is much complex. I add pieces of code to make it a sample code. It works except in my actual app, the view attached to tab is a modal behind tab bar whereas in this sample, it's main view. But the issue is reproducible with this sample code.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SimpleDataView()
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            BottomTabView()
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleDataView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Map will be displayed over here").background(Color.gray).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct BottomTabView: View {
    @State private var defaultHandleColor = Color.secondary
    @State private var activeHandleColor = Color.primary
    @State private var sliderHandleHeight: CGFloat = 15.0
    @State private var radius: CGFloat = 16
    
    /// The latest recorded drag gesture value.
    @State var latestDragGesture: DragGesture.Value?
    @State private var maximumHeight: CGFloat = .infinity
    @State private var isPanelExpanding: Bool = false
    @State private var handleColor = Color.secondary

    
    @State var selection: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Group {
                ZStack {
                    SearchExploreModalView()
                }.tabItem {
                    Label("Explore", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Explore")
                }
                .tag(1)
                .gesture(drag)
            }
        }
        .background(Color(red: 0.98, green: 0.98, blue: 0.98).opacity(0.94))
        .onAppear {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
    }
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged {
                let deltaY = $0.location.y - (latestDragGesture?.location.y ?? $0.location.y)
                let proposedHeight = 250.0 + (-1 * deltaY)
                self.isPanelExpanding = proposedHeight >= 250.0 ? true : false
                handleColor = activeHandleColor
                latestDragGesture = $0
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                // On Ended logic
            }
    }
}

struct SearchExploreModalView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    let searchTextPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    // For loop iterating overdata
                }
                .searchable(
                    text: $searchText,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always),
                    prompt: "Search"
                )
                .onChange(of: searchText) { newText in
                    searchTextPublisher.send(newText) /// Publishes when a search term is changed. This is used to debounce the search.
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do any of the below solutions solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some conflict of priority between the different gestures on screen that is causing something to go wrong behind the scenes.

This might be a bug, so maybe a future visitor to this question can weigh in.

I was able to get it to work by adding an empty `onTapGesture` on the line prior to `.gesture` - see below:

```
 struct BottomTabView: View {
    @State private var defaultHandleColor = Color.secondary
    @State private var activeHandleColor = Color.primary
    @State private var sliderHandleHeight: CGFloat = 15.0
    @State private var radius: CGFloat = 16
    
    /// The latest recorded drag gesture value.
    @State var latestDragGesture: DragGesture.Value?
    @State private var maximumHeight: CGFloat = .infinity
    @State private var isPanelExpanding: Bool = false
    @State private var handleColor = Color.secondary

    
    @State var selection: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Group {
                ZStack {
                    SearchExploreModalView()
                }.tabItem {
                    Label("Explore", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Explore")
                }
                .tag(1)
                .onTapGesture {} // <-- Here!!
                .gesture(drag)
            }
        }
        .background(Color(red: 0.98, green: 0.98, blue: 0.98).opacity(0.94))
        .onAppear {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
    }
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged {
                print("hihihihi")
                let deltaY = $0.location.y - (latestDragGesture?.location.y ?? $0.location.y)
                let proposedHeight = 250.0 + (-1 * deltaY)
                self.isPanelExpanding = proposedHeight >= 250.0 ? true : false
                handleColor = activeHandleColor
                latestDragGesture = $0
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                // On Ended logic
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you added the gesture to the `NavigationView`, which contains the search bar. When you tap on the search bar, SwiftUI prioritises your drag gesture, instead of the search bar's built-in tap gesture.

The behaviour of gestures in the superview overriding built-in gestures in the subviews seems to be a common problem. See also: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73292506/5133585), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68463020/5133585), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76386136/5133585), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74873664/5133585)

One way to fix this is simply to not add the gesture on the `NavigationView`. Add it to the `List` instead.

```
struct SearchExploreModalView<T: Gesture>: View {
    ...

    let drag: T

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ...
                }
                ...
                .gesture(drag) // <--- here!
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        ...

    }
}
```

Of course, this makes some parts of the `NavigationView` (e.g. toolbar buttons) not able to detect the gesture. You can try adding the same gesture to those parts of the `NavigationView` too.

Alternatively, set a higher `minimumDistance` for the drag gesture to succeed.

```
DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1, coordinateSpace: .global)
```

This allows the search bar's tap gesture to succeed when you are just tapping it.